# My custom jQuery widget doesn't work after upgrading to jQuery UI 1.10

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a simple widget, which structure is like this:

```
(function ($, undefined) {    
     $.ui.newslettersignup = {
      _create: function () {
         console.log('dosomething');
      },
      destroy: function () {
          // if using jQuery UI 1.8.x
          $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
          // if using jQuery UI 1.9.x
          //this._destroy();
      },
      options:{

      }
    };
    $.widget("ui.newslettersignup", $.ui.newslettersignup);
})(jQuery);
```

But after upgrading jQuery and JQuery-UI to 1.10 from 1.8.3, I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.js:632
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:632
$.widget jquery.ui.widget.js:123
(anonymous function) ui.newslettersignup.js:47
(anonymous function)
```

I have tried to look at the update notes, but I haven't seen any mentions of changes to the jQuery.UI.Widget.

If I debug in the browser I can see that, $.ui.newslettersignup is available, but doing $('something').newslettersignup(); gives me the error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'newslettersignup'
```

NB. The update is done through the two Rails gems "jquery-rails" and "jquery-ui-rails".

Comment: Look into jQuery Migrate. It can tell you what features have changed/been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the jQuery UI Widgets, and changed the syntax to :

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget("ui.newslettersignup", {
        _create: function() {
        },
        options: {}
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and it then worked. I still couldn't find the notes about why it was changed, or why this didn't work anymore.